# What happens with a globular cluster when it passes through a galactic disc?

Tags: galaxy, globular-clusters

The orbits of globular clusters are crossing the disks of their galaxies, so they should sometimes pass through the disks. Are there any observed fluctuations in the clusters and in the disks themselves caused by such crossings?